# unable to send message from nodejs backend with res.json to angularjs frontend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, response, frontend, backend

Doing a post with multer, I want to send the error message from nodejs backend with

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
   destination: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, '../uploads');
   },
   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null,  file.originalname + '-' + Date.now());
   }
});

router.post('/upload', function(req, res){
            upload(req, res, function(err) {
            if(err){ 
                        res.json({ Status : false, message : err})
                        }else{ 
                        res.json({ Status : true, message : 'Success'})
               }
        })
    })
```

to the angular controller

```
$http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/upload'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          if(response.data.Status){ 
              console.log(response.data.message);
          }
          else{ 
              console.log(response.data.message); 
          }
      })
```

to show the backend success or error in the frontend console.
But it only opens an empty page with `{"Status":true,"message":"Success"}`
html:

```
<form enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
      action    =  "/upload"
      method    =  "POST">

Select File:

<input type="file" name="file" >
<p></p>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

</form>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: where is your upload function?

Comment: @abdulbarik edited it above. Doing my upload with multer.

Comment: what are you getting in `response.data` in angular side? always same message?

Comment: Please share your upload function or print that err in callback

Comment: I want to get the data from the backend. To show in the frontend if the upload worked.

Comment: are you able to upload your file and your upload callback is calling?

Comment: @abdulbarik I am able to upload and the console in the backend logs what I want it to log.

Comment: @Deepakrao added my html above

Comment: use ng-submit. dont use type = submit. refer: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit. type submit will refresh you page

Comment: @Deepakrao put ng-submit="submit()" in the form start tag but the new page still opens..